# how to use a local Library with an executable jar

Tags: spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

I want to create a deployable docker image of my backend. So I am trying to have the complete production image with a fat executable jar.

I have used the the assembly plugin for a first version and it works well.

In a second version of my project, I am using a local jar library.
I added it to the dependencies. To test the integration using mvn spring-boot:run, it works fine.
However, when I created the executable jar file of the whole project. It does not succeed. I got an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:. 
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Have you any idea or links to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your application from a standalone jar, then your jar must contain all the dependent jar within it. This type of jar know as fat or executable jar. Maven does not create fat jar automatically for you. You need to add the below plugin to your pom.xml to create the executable jar.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>{abc.cde.YourMainClass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
           </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```